# Fade color to transparency with css

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

I would like to reproduce the navbar in the below picture using html and CSS, but I can't wrap my head around that fade that turns white into transparent.

[image]

I've searched the internet with no success.
For now this is my attempt:
`background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 100%);`, but it isn't really working.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/p7rm49V.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-container {
  height: 4rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 15px 15px;
  grid-template-areas: "back-button-area brand-title-area empty-cell";
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
}

.back-button-area {
  grid-area: back-button-area;
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.brand-title-area {
  grid-area: brand-title-area;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.empty-cell {
  grid-area: empty-cell;
}

.back-button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d5d9d9;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: rgba(213, 217, 217, .5) 0 2px 5px 0;
  color: #0f1111;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Amazon Ember", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}

.back-button:hover {
  background-color: #f7fafa;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar-container">
    <div class="back-button-area">
      <span class="back-button">&#x276E;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="brand-title-area">Find Bike</div>
    <div class="empty-cell"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="map"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. There's no need for a codepen for this.

Comment: Maybe you are a little bit confused about transparent. Your code tells me, the main body 's background is white. I'll give you screenshot and code worked on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

With your code, the `.map` div starts *below* the navbar – in the regular document flow. Since the background behind the navbar in this situation is white (by default), you don't see the transparency effect of your gradient. Add `position: absolute` and `width: 100%` to the navbar to move the `.map` div *under* (= partly behind) the navbar:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/p7rm49V.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-container {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr; 
  gap: 15px 15px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "back-button-area brand-title-area empty-cell"; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 100%);
}
.back-button-area { grid-area: back-button-area;
  justify-self: start; 
  align-self: center; 
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.brand-title-area { grid-area: brand-title-area; 
  justify-self: center; 
  align-self: center; 
}
.empty-cell { grid-area: empty-cell; }


.back-button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d5d9d9;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: rgba(213, 217, 217, .5) 0 2px 5px 0;
  color: #0f1111;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Amazon Ember",sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}
.back-button:hover {background-color: #f7fafa;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar-container">
    <div class="back-button-area">
      <span class="back-button">&#x276E;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="brand-title-area">Find Bike</div>
    <div class="empty-cell"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="map"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to make your bar position absolute so it lays over the map. As it was the map is pushed below it.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/p7rm49V.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-container {
  height: 4rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 15px 15px;
  grid-template-areas: "back-button-area brand-title-area empty-cell";
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #fff 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.back-button-area {
  grid-area: back-button-area;
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.brand-title-area {
  grid-area: brand-title-area;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.empty-cell {
  grid-area: empty-cell;
}

.back-button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d5d9d9;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: rgba(213, 217, 217, .5) 0 2px 5px 0;
  color: #0f1111;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Amazon Ember", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}

.back-button:hover {
  background-color: #f7fafa;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar-container">
    <div class="back-button-area">
      <span class="back-button">&#x276E;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="brand-title-area">Find Bike</div>
    <div class="empty-cell"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="map"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this code and image.

```html
<body class="map">
  <div class="navbar-container">
    <div class="back-button-area">
      <span class="back-button">&#x276E;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="brand-title-area">Find Bike</div>
    <div class="empty-cell"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="#"></div>
</body>
```

and

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/p7rm49V.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-container {
  height: 4rem;
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr; 
  gap: 15px 15px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "back-button-area brand-title-area empty-cell"; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 30%);
}
.back-button-area { grid-area: back-button-area;
  justify-self: start; 
  align-self: center; 
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.brand-title-area { grid-area: brand-title-area; 
  justify-self: center; 
  align-self: center; 
}
.empty-cell { grid-area: empty-cell; }


.back-button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d5d9d9;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: rgba(213, 217, 217, .5) 0 2px 5px 0;
  color: #0f1111;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Amazon Ember",sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}
.back-button:hover {background-color: #f7fafa;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the code below along with your .navbar-container class CSS.

```
position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 width: 100%;
```

So, the final CSS of .navbar-container  class will look like this,

```
.navbar-container {
   position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr; 
  gap: 15px 15px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "back-button-area brand-title-area empty-cell"; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 100%);
}
```

Tried your code pan and it looks like this with the above CSS https://prnt.sc/swguSQMAIcNM.

Hope this helps.